# I created a web app that displays gas value and current value but it does not store data in the database

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, web-applications, raspberry-pi3

The web app  displays gas value and current value, it includes graphs, the status of led, buzzer, and solenoid. It has login, logout, and signup. The database contains only the data for the email address of the user but the data for gas data and current data, there is none.
The problem is the value for gas and current when it reaches the threshold it does not store data in the database.

Here is the table that I created
Database models:
models.py:

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Float, DateTime
gas_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class GasData(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    gas_value = db.Column(db.Float)
    gas_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class CurrentData(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    current_value = db.Column(db.Float)
    current_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp()) 
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))`
```

in views.py:

```
def home():
gas_value = mq6_modules[0].mq.MQPercentage()["GAS_LPG"]
current_value = powers[0].get_electricalsensor_readings()

if gas_value >= 0.2:
    flash('High gas value detected!', 'danger')  # Add flash message
    gas_reading = GasData(gas_value=gas_value,user_id=current_user.id)
    db.session.add(gas_reading)
    db.session.commit()


if current_value is not None and float(current_value) >= 0.2:
    flash('High current value detected!', 'danger') 
    current_reading = CurrentData(current_value=current_value, user_id=current_user.id)
    db.session.add(current_reading)
    db.session.commit()
return render_template("home.html", user=current_user)
```

Here is the whole code for my web app: [text](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ygFICqwuEcJj6z92zGfOljchyQr3RM1s?usp=sharing)

I already did this to check if there is data inside the database:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd Documents
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents $ cd "FLASK WEB APP"
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/FLASK WEB APP $ cd instance
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/FLASK WEB APP/instance $ ls
aegis.db  database.db
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/FLASK WEB APP/instance $ sqlite3 database.db
SQLite version 3.34.1 2021-01-20 14:10:07
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
current_data     gas_data         note
current_reading  gas_reading      user
sqlite> select * from current_reading
...> ;

```
sqlite> select * from gas_reading
   ...> ;
sqlite> select * from current_data;
sqlite> select * from gas_data;`
```